# JWT Token Forcefully expire in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I want to **Expire** Existing **JWT Access Token and Refresh Token** while i call login api and generate new access and refresh token.
i am use **JwtSecurityTokenHandler** for generating access token. i also put **Expires** for expiring token. But I want To **Expire Forcefully** Existing access and refresh token .

Answer (score 1):

`Expire Forcefully` is called `Revoke` in term of JWT. However, in the natural JWT token doesn't want to be revoked because it `defines a compact and self-contained way for securely transmitting information between parties` [here](https://jwt.io/introduction/). So you don't want to call `revoke`, it will make your system is overhead.

However, many enterprise systems require a mechanism to stop `JWT` immediately. So you should build a `cache solution` to store all provided tokens. Then each time user call your API, your API server must be validated once again with your `Identity Server` instead of itself, that is invalid with the term of **self-contained**. But that depends on your choice, I recommend you to use `Redis Distributed Cache` to force `expire` your provided token, at least this solution can be scale.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, in case of user is deactivated or removed from the system need to expire the tokens generated against the user. For this, I made a validation in the JWT bearer middleware.

```
services.AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        x.SaveToken = true;
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidIssuer = "localhost",
            ValidAudience = "localhost"
        };
        x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            OnTokenValidated = context =>
            {
                var UserGUID = context.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Sid).Value;
                var user = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserManager>().GetUserAsync(UserGUID, string.Empty, false).Result;
                var failed = user == null || !user.IsActive;
                if (failed)
                    context.Fail(new Exception("Token not valid anymore"));
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    })
```